# Is it possible to combine rake task and bundle install into one command?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler, take

I have several `rake tasks` combined into one rake command. Just wondering is it possible to have one command run the "`bundle install`" within a rake task ?

Or other way around ?

So when I deploy my rails app to a new server all I need to do is just run one command and it will grab all the dependencies and migrate databases settings.yaml files etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can chained your command with &&

For example :

```
rake my_task && bundle install
```

It's poor response but it's work ;-)

Obviously you can make your script

vi ./scripts/deploy.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
rake my_task && bundle install
```

Comment: thanks! never thought about create a script to run those command inline cool!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this been done `bundle install && bundle exec rake db:migrate`